# Hibernate 4.3.1 - Native query on multiple table returns just one record

Tags: oracle, hibernate, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I am using Hibernate 4.3.1 to fetch records from four different unrelated tables by using columns which have matching data. For this I have written a query which is as follows

```
SELECT ca.csc_issuer_id as cssIssuerId,
       ca.csc_serial_number as cssSerialNumber,
       ca.csc_type as cssType,
       ca.csc_lifecycle_count as cssLifecycleCount,
       aa.app_provider_id as ...,
       aa.provider_app_serial_number as ...,
       aa.card_app_serial_number as ..,
       aa.app_type as ..,     
       pa.csc_issuer_id as ..,
       pa.csc_serial_number as ..,
       pa.prodType  
  FROM AATable AA, CATable CA, PATable PA          
 WHERE AA.CSC_SERIAL_NUMBER = CA.CSC_SERIAL_NUMBER 
       AND AA.CSC_SERIAL_NUMBER = PA.CSC_SERIAL_NUMBER
       AND AA.CSC_SERIAL_NUMBER = 123456
       AND AA.csc_issuer_id = 26
       AND AA.csc_type = 1
       AND AA.csc_lifecycle_count = 0
       AND PA.app_provider_id = 26
       AND PA.provider_app_serial_number = 123456
       AND PA.card_app_serial_number = 0
```

This query return 3 rows when I run it directly on Oracle database(All of them obviously match all the where condition but each row has a different value of PATable.prodType column) but when I use this from within my java code , Hibernate only returns one row which is the first row returned by SQL.Any idea whats going on ?  I have tried joining tables but the same result.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class MyPOJO {
private Long cssIssuerId;
private Long cssSerialNumber
other members....
}
```

Comment: Do you use an entity to map result data? In this entity "Id" annotation is used? Hibernate return only results with different values in "Id" fields.

Comment: @FrancescoSerra Thanks. I am mapping the results to a POJO and not the entity. I use `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyPOJO.class));` and reading the results as `List<MyPOJO> results = query.list();`

Comment: How do you map your table (or query result) to the POJO class?

Comment: Using `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyPOJO.c‌​lass));` And my POJO class has all the fields returned by this query.

Comment: Can you post MyPOJO.java code and the mapping file?

Comment: I have added the POJO class details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158360/discussion-between-java2017-and-francesco-serra).